# Rails 4 - not able to rearrange columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, database-schema, rails-migrations

I've been browsing through stack to find how to rearrange columns inside my table, but for example this code below didn't work. I have table called mains, and column called photo which I want to put after body column. I have used this code:

```
class ChangePhotoAfterBody < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :mains, :photo, :string, after: :body
  end
end
```

But still didn't manage to rearrange them inside my schema file when I ran rake db:migrate, and when later I tried to rollback this migration I got massive activerecord 4.0.4 error:

```
:~/Pulpit/Aptana3_Workspace/My_webpage$ rake db:rollback
== 20140620062825 ChangePhotoAfterBody: reverting =============================
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration/home/mateusz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration/command_recorder.rb:65:in `inverse_of'
/home/mateusz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/activerecord-4.0.4/lib/active_record/migration/command_recorder.rb:50:in `record'
...
...
...
```

And here you have my schema file:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140620062825) do
  create_table "mains", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "body"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "photo"
  end
end
```

My questions are: 1) Does migration name make any difference for rake db:migrate command? , 2) Why is this migration irreversible? / Why did this error occur?, 4) How to rearrange my columns inside my schema?

Comment: When you do `rake db:migrate`,the changes occurred in the `DB`?

Comment: Just for my ease of mind: You are rearranging the database for some architectural reason, and not because you want your rendered output ordered differently?

Comment: No, changes didn't occur inside my database ,but rake db:migrate didn't show any errors, it was successful. But later I can't rollback this migration.

Comment: I'm doing it because I want to learn how to do it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do a `rake:rollback` you need to separate your migration like this:

```
def self.up
  #Your migration columns
end

def self.down
  #Your migration columns to come back to the original schema
end
```

Now, when you'll call `rake:rollback` Rake will know what to do.

Comment: Ok it works, but let me clear some things up, If I no longer want to have a migration I change migration's method's name to def self.down, and I use def self.up when I want to have this migration in use, am I correct?

Comment: You should never edit a migration when you already did the migration. That can create a lot of critical problems in your database. What I use to do is to define `up` and `down` when I want to be very clean and I want a possible way back. If not, you can use directly `change`.

Answer (score 2):

```
`\db\migrate/20140620062825.rb`

try this !

    class ChangePhotoAfterBody < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
    create_table :mains do |t|
    t.string :title
    t.text :body
    t.string :photo
    t.timestamps
    end
    end

4) How to rearrange my columns inside my schema?

    ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140620062825) do
    create_table "mains", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "body"
    t.string   "photo"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    end
    end

1st step==> rake db:drop    
2nd step==> rake db:create   
last step==> rake db:migrate
```